# Testing Prolog Difference lists

Tags: list, prolog, difference-lists

I've been reading about how great difference lists are and I was hoping to test some examples from the books. But it seems that you can't pass lists as input in just the same way as, for instance append([1,2,3], [4,5], X), where X=[1,2,3,4,5]. Strangely, no book I've consulted ever mentions this.

I'm running the code on swipl and I'm interested in testing out a difference append predicate:

```
dapp(A-B,B-C,A-C).
```

and a "rotate first element of list" predicate:

```
drotate([H|T]-T1,R-S) :- dapp(T-T1,[H|L]-L,R-S).
```

Any ideas, how I can test these predicates in swipl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
dapp([1,2,3|X] - X,[4,5,6] - [],Y - []).
drotate([1,2,3|X] - X,Y - []).
```

Y is the answer for both predicates.

Comment: That did the trick! I never thought about trying Y-[], thanks!

Comment: actually, it could be anything, just make make sure it's the same for 2nd and 3rd argument. e.g.: dapp([1,2,3|X] - X,[4,5,6] - Z,Y - Z).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `drotate` can be simplified:

```ml
dapp( A-B, B-C, A-C). 
drotate( [H|T]-T1, R-S) :- % (* dapp( T-T1, [H|L]-L, R-S). 
       %%                       dapp( A-B , B    -C, A-C). 
       %% use the definition of dapp: *)
                             T = R, T1 = [H|L], L = S.
```

In other words, simply,

```ml
drotate( [H|R]-[H|L], R-L).
```

Now, any difference list is usually written out as a pair, `A-B`. So a call to `drotate` might be `drotate( [1,2,3|Z]-Z, R-L)` with intent to see the output in `R-L` variables. But matching this call with the last definition, we get `Z = [1|L]`, i.e. the logvar `Z`, presumably non-instantiated before the call, gets instantiated by it, actually adding `1` at the end of the open-ended list `[1,2,3|Z]-Z`, turning it into `[1,2,3,1|L]-L`. `R` just gets pointed at the 2nd element of the newly enlarged list by matching `[H|R]` with the list.

```ml
?- drotate( [1,2,3|Z]-Z, R-L).

Z = [1|_G345]
R = [2, 3, 1|_G345]
L = _G345 

Yes
```

But it could also be called with the truly circular data, `A-A = [1,2,3|Z]-Z, drotate( A-Z, R-L)`:

```ml
?- A-A = [1,2,3|Z]-Z, drotate( A-Z, R-L).

A = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3|...]
Z = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3|...]
R = [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1|...]
L = [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1|...] 

Yes
```